# How to delete Oracle 11g driver

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have remove the oracle 11g (following [How do I do a manual uninstall of Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83967/how-do-i-do-a-manual-uninstall-of-oracle))
Then install the oracle 12

However, I'm getting a ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error, when I'm using new oracle.
Its look like there are still some references to old oracle.

[image]
As per picture above, how do I delete oraclient11g_home1 in windows?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the ODBC admin here.  It's not about deleting the driver, it's about redefining your DSN to use the new driver.

As for actually removing the driver, if you uninstalled oracle, then the only thing to be removed is two entries in the Windows registry.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to a system with Windblows, so cannot give you the details.  If you are not experienced in mucking about in the registry, you could just leave that in place, as it is not hurting anything.

Comment: How do I redefining DSN to use the new drive?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Registry editor and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in OraClient11g_home1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers\Oracle in OraClient11g_home1
```

Delete the keys/values. Then the ODBC driver is removed. However as mentioned by @EdStevens this may not solve your problem.

Comment: Deleting the registry key fixed the Oracle 11 appearing on ODBC driver list but I'm still getting the ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error. Which  means, I need to redefining  DSN to use the new drive. How I'm gonna do that?

Comment: _" I need to redefining DSN to use the new drive. How I'm gonna do that?"_   In the ODBC admin (the one you gave the screen shot for, click on one of the 3 'DSN' tabs --  probably the System DSN.  Click on the DSN in question.  Click on 'Configure'.